# How to create and run a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need somebody to help me check my coding and give me the solution to get the output.
This is my coding:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

    private String name, msg;

    public MyThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Child Thread : starts its execution");

        for (int i = 5 ; i > 0 ; i--) {

            System.out.println(name + " says: " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }

        System.out.println(name + " finished execution");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Main Thread");
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Child Thread");

        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();

    }
}
```

The output should be like this:

[image]

But my coding is not working (logic error).
Anyone can help me to get the output as above?

Comment: You can barely get such output. The execution order of threads is unpredictable, so it's very odd that you will get the same output unless you use synchronization between your threads but that would be overkill for this example.

Comment: Can you please share what you are getting output from this ?

Comment: You are creating and running the threads correctly. Your title is misleading as this is not the problem. You need to learn about synchronization and find a way to synchronize your threads to alternate back and forth.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OP doesn't need to synchronize. Note how the threads overlap when writing 2 and 1.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OIC...I just looked at the first several outputs which are alternating threads.

Comment: Note that you cannot guarantee the order that threads execute. That is both the strength and weakness of using threads.

Comment: Just start one child thread and run a second count-down loop in the main thread. You should not expect your output to be exactly like the sample output, just approximately like it (with output from the two threads intermingled).

Comment: Actually this is one of question from my assignment. So I thought my lecturer got output exactly as above. Anyway many thanks.

Comment: @AzZahraMuhammad try the below answer and let us know if it works for u

Comment: Your lecturer probably got this output just one time.  He/she wouldn't have been able to reproduce it, with two threads running.  You can, of course, do fancy synchronisation with `wait` and `notify`, but to do that is missing the point of using threads.  So your program looks just fine to me already, except for the fact that you don't seem to have the line that prints `Child Thread: Thread[Demo Thread,5,main]`

Comment: Alright. Many thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have given comments. Feel free to ask any doubts

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private String name, msg;
    private int interval; // to specify the period to be used to take lock. Main thread needs to do it for every iteration whereas childthread should do it for 2 iterations
    private static Object lock = new Object(); // to use wait and notify mechanism to get the desired output
    private static boolean done = false; // to make sure that if the child thread is done with its tasks then main thread need not wait

    public MyThread(String name, int interval) {
        this.name = name; 
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        synchronized (lock) {

            System.out.println(name+" Thread : starts its execution");

            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {

                System.out.println(name + " says: " +i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

                // Main thread waits for every iteration
                // Child thread waits for every 2 iterations
                if(!done && ++count % interval == 0) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Once child thread is done with its iterations, main thread need not wait anymore hence set done to true
            done = true;
            // to make sure that if the main thread is waiting then give it a signal to finish its tasks with no more waiting
            lock.notifyAll();
            System.out.println(name + " finished execution");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread("Main Thread",1);
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread("Child Thread",2);

        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();

    }

}
```